# Custom View on a table in the administration console

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple table in my Django app that looks like:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    value= models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
```

For reasons, I'm storing the data as key value pairs. I'm the administration console, I'd like to represent this Model pivoted i.e. transpose the rows to become columns. I'd like to it behave as any other model admin.

For example when record is saved, I'll be iterating over the fields and saving them which I'll do a over-ridden manager method. When the admin tries to list all the rows from this view, Id would iterating over the key-value pairs and pivoting them.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot figure what are you trying to achieve. Maybe give some more details or explanations?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - make the fields in admin's object [list editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable):

```
class SettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('group', 'name', 'value')
    list_editable = ('value',)    # Fields that will be editable
    list_display_links = ()
```

If that's not satisfactory, you can use [custom template file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template) for the change list view. You need to prepare a template file that will render your data and set the path in ModelAdmin:

```
class SettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'setting_change_list.html'
```